# Apache cordova - unable to write to file in android

Tags: javascript, android, apache, cordova, cordova-3

I am trying to create a file in the PERSISTENT (sd card) storage using cordova's api in javascript. I am able to create the file, but unable to write data to it (data is empty on read). Below is my JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
});

function onDeviceReady() {
    writeTestList();
}

function writeTestList() {
     window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFileSystemForWrite, function() { showMsg('Unable to access file system for write'); });
  }

function gotFileSystemForWrite(fileSystem) {
    fileSystem.root.getFile('testList.txt', {create: true, exclusive: false}, gotFileEntryForWrite, function() { showMsg('Unable to access file for write'); });
}

function gotFileEntryForWrite(fileEntry) {
   fileEntry.createWriter(gotFileWriter, function() { showMsg('Unable to create test list'); });
}

function gotFileWriter(writer) {
    writer.onwrite = function(evt) {
      // show a message
      alert('created the test lists');
      readSavedContent();
   };
   writer.onerror = function(evt) {
     alert(JSON.stringify(evt));
   };
   writer.write("raj");
   alert(writer.length);
}
```

The control always goes inside onerror of writer and on alerting the event obj, i see a type: "error", error: "JSON error". I completely don't get this. I am writing to a txt file, but getting json error. I have put write permissions in android manifest. Also, I have storage plugin for cordova enabled in config.xml preferences. People, pls help me out with this..!!

Comment: could you please say how to make your code work? I get an error: requestFileSystem is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unable to fix this issue in cordova 3.0. Moved to cordova 2.9 and everything works perfectly.